# Open Google Map externally (PhoneGap)

Tags: android, html, cordova, google-maps, geo

I am using PhoneGap in order to create an Android app. However, I have faced an issue. I would like to open Google Maps (app) through my app, however, the app does not respond on the href.

I am using the PhoneGap app in the Google Play Store in order to debug my app -> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.phonegap.app&hl=nl

Code:

```html
<a href="geo:38.897096,-77.036545">open map</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your href is not ok, try this

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/@-38.897096,-77.036545,8z,">open map</a>
```

Comment: Why not? He want to open google maps with coords with an href, and this is the solution, he only have to change the href to a real maps url, and the app will open

Comment: This,unfortunately, does not work. I will try the answer of johnborges now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you allow the external apps you're launching to your whitelist in `config.xml`. `<allow-intent href="geo:*" />`. An alternative to using `geo:` is to use the [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) Plugin. `cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.google.com/maps/@-38.897096,-77.036545,8z,', '_system', 'location=yes');`

Comment: That, sadly, does not work. Is it due to the PhoneGap Developer app? I am not launching the app via an .apk file.

Answer (score 0):

```
function openMap(may_latitude, may_longitude) {

    if (device.platform === 'iOS') {
        window.open("http://maps.apple.com/?q=" + may_latitude + ","
                + may_longitude, '_system');
    } else {

        window.open("http://maps.google.com/?q=" + may_latitude + ","
                + may_longitude, '_system');
    }
}
```